# Kafka consumer side failure handling and redelivery

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

What happens if some of the messages not Ack'ed back in kafka. Lets say I am consuming messages concurrently. And one consumer not able to process the message with offset=20 and didn't send Ack back. But other message with offset=21 been consumed and ack back. How can I replay only 20?

Do I need to put message to DLQ and consume again? what if failure happens there also?

I am little confused with guaranteed delivery.

Answer (score 5):

If you use group management, where kafka assigns the partitions, it can't happen - a partition is assigned to one thread only. If you have more threads, they are each consuming from a different partition which each have their own offset.

Comment: What happens for the batch mode? If some messages been consumed and and some not?

Comment: In batch mode, you will lilely get some duplicates.

Comment: Given that I choose to pick earliest as my offset while starting my consumer?

Answer (score 0):

In you case, your latest committed offset is 21. and Kafka assume your 20 also committed. So when you restart it will start from offset 21. Yes. I remember Gary mention that you either need to stop the container at 20 or put the 20 to some other topic for later reply.